# Getting a random sample in Python dataframe by category

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a sample list like this:

```
Category| Item
--------|-------
Animal  | Fish
Animal  | Cat
...     |
Food    | Fish
Food    | Cake
...     |
etc...
```

I want to take a random sample of 10 items out of each category, so that the remaining dataframe just has those records.

I've tried `df.sample()` but it just gives me samples across the board.

I can do this this through `df.iterrows()` but I am hoping there is a more simple solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to tell pandas you want to group by category with the `groupby` method.

```
df.groupby('category')['item'].apply(lambda s: s.sample(10))
```

If you have less than ten items in a sample but don't want to sample with replacement you can do this.

```
df.groupby('category')['item'].apply(lambda s: s.sample(min(len(s), 10)))
```

Comment: I get an error as not all categories have 10 items in it. So I had to change to `s.sample(10, replace=True)`. Otherwise this works! Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want to sample with replacement you can just keep all the items for categories with less than 10. See the updated answer.

Comment: Should be s. Fixed

Answer (score 6):

I have an `imbalanced` dataset and I used the following code to `balance` the dataset with 100 samples (rows) per each class (label) of the dataset with the duplicate.`activity` is my classes. This code is used for `oversampling` instances of the minority class or `undersampling` instances of the majority class. It should be used only on the training set.

```
balanced_df=Pdf_train.groupby('activity',as_index = False,group_keys=False).apply(lambda s: s.sample(100,replace=True))
```